# What is it that frees Bisq from all these KYC/AML laws and regulations?

Tags: privacy, legal, aml, know-your-customer, bisq

I feel as if I should probably not ask about this, and instead just quietly go on using it in my little corner, not bringing any attention to its existence, but I still must ask:

What is it that enables Bisq (the decentralized exchange software/network) from not having to follow KYC/AML laws/regulations?

The obvious answer may be "it's decentralized", but let's be real: their website, forum and Github repo are all very much centralized, and this is the only way that I and 99% of its users would be able to get any updates, and probably for the already installed software to be able to fetch updates as well. Even decentralized applications always have some sort of "hardcoded bootstrap list of nodes", whether by hostname or IP address. Basically, decentralized anything is kind of an illusion in this Internet.

So, if it gets too big and thus poses a real threat, can't "they" just shut it down extremely easily by just taking away the domains/Github accounts, or just going after the public individuals who are known to run/develop the software?

Isn't it only because so few people use/know about it that they "get away" with this?

Comment: Bisq software used for trading will work without website, forum and github repository or you can always create new website, forum and repository.

Comment: @Prayank Then how does Bisq find other nodes and fetch updates? Certainly not by magic.